# Render component template on invoked methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So while I'm learning vue, I wanted to double check if someone can show me what I'm doing wrong or lead me in the right answer. Below, I will show the code and then explain what I'm attempting to do.

Here is my `Vue.js` app:

```
Vue.component('o365_apps_notifications', {
    template:
    `
    <div class="notification is-success is-light">
        // Call the name here and if added/removed.
    </div>
   `,

});

new Vue({
    name: 'o365-edit-modal',
    el: '#o365-modal-edit',
    components: 'o365_apps_notifications',
    data() {
        return {
            list: {},
            movable: true,
            editable: true,
            isDragging: false,
            delayedDragging: false,
            options: {
                group: 'o365apps',
                disabled: true,
                handle: '.o365_app_handle',
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        add(index, obj) {
            console.log(obj.name);
            this.$data.list.selected.push(...this.$data.list.available.splice(index, 1));
            this.changed();
        },
        remove(index, obj) {
            console.log(obj.name);
            this.$data.list.available.push(...this.$data.list.selected.splice(index, 1));
            this.changed();
        },
        checkMove(evt) {
            console.log(evt.draggedContext.element.name);
        },
    },
});
```

Here is my modal:

```html
<div id="o365-modal-edit" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-card px-4">
        <header class="modal-card-head">
            <p class="modal-card-title">Applications</p>
            <button class="delete" aria-label="close"></button>
        </header>
        <section class="modal-card-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="o365-modal-edit-wrapper">
                    <div class="columns">
                        <div class="column is-half-desktop is-full-mobile buttons">
                            // Empty
                        </div>
                        <div class="column is-half-desktop is-full-mobile buttons">
                            // Empty
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer class="modal-card-foot">
            <o365-apps-notifications></o365-apps-notifications>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Here is what I'm attempting to do**:

Inside my modal, I have my `o365_apps_notifications` html tag called, my `add()` and `remove()` methods output a name on each add/remove using `console.log(obj.name);` and my `checkMove` method also drags the same name on drag as shown below:

1. How could I get my component to render and output the name inside the modal footer? I've tried all methods, but I can't seem to figure out how to trigger the component.
2. Also, would I have to do something special to make the component fade out after a set timeframe?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to define a prop on your notification component. Instead of writing to console, store the name in a variable, and link that to the prop on the notification component. Check the Vue documentation for this, it's essential to understand this while doing Vue programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple issues:

1. You've declared the notification component with underscores (`o365_apps_notifications`), but used hyphens in the modal's template. They should be consistent (the convention is hyphens).
2. The notification component is declared globally (with `Vue.component`), but it looks like you're trying to add it to the modal's `components`, which is intended for local components. Only one registration is needed (the global component registration should do).

#### `<o365-apps-notifications>`

The notification component should have [public `props`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props) that take the item name and state:

```js
Vue.component('o365-apps-notifications', {
  props: {
    item: String,
    isAdded: Boolean
  },
})
```

Then, its template could use data binding to display these props.

```js
Vue.component('o365-apps-notifications', {
  template:
   `<div>
      {{ item }} {{ isAdded ? 'added' : 'removed '}}
    </div>`
})
```

For the fade transition, we want to [conditionally render](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) this data based on a local Boolean [data property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) (e.g., named `show`):

```js
Vue.component('o365-apps-notifications', {
  template:
   `<div v-if="show">
      ...
    </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      show: false
    }
  }
})
```

...and add the [`<transition>` element](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components) along with CSS to style the fade:

```js
Vue.component('o365-apps-notifications', {
  template:
   `<transition name="fade">
      <div v-if="show">
        ...
      </div>
    </transition>`,
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

To automatically fade out the data, add a [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) on `item`, which sets `show=true` and then `show=false` after a delay:

```js
Vue.component('o365-apps-notifications', {
  watch: {
    item(item) {
      if (!item) {
        return;
      }
      this.show = true;

      clearTimeout(this._timer);
      this._timer = setTimeout(() => this.show = false, 1000);
    }
  }
})
```

#### Usage

In the modal component, declare local data properties that hold the currently added/removed item:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#o365-modal-edit',
  data() {
    return {
      changedItem: null,
      changedItemIsAdded: false,
    }
  },
})
```

Also update `add()` and `remove()` to set these properties:

```js
new Vue({
  methods: {
    add(index, obj) {
      this.changedItem = obj.name;
      this.changedItemIsAdded = true;
    },
    remove(index, obj) {
      this.changedItem = obj.name;
      this.changedItemIsAdded = false;
    },
  },
})
```

Then in the modal component's template, bind these properties to the notification component's props:

```html
<o365-apps-notifications :item="changedItem" :is-added="changedItemIsAdded"></o365-apps-notifications>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/BaQdXRR)

Comment: Tony! Thanks so much for explaining all the steps man! I can't believe some of the things that I missed, including the underscores and hyphens to begin with, what a mistake on the consistency part on my end. This explains things perfectly.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks so much for explaining each item in detail, I will be learning on this when I start building out my favorites module.

Comment: Hey Tony, got a quick question - Let's say that I want to have it display class `is-primary` on added and `is-danger` on remove inside our template, would I pass that as a prop also?

Comment: You could use the existing `isAdded` prop with a [class binding](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax).

Comment: Thanks Tony! I'm going to look into class binding now, that is such a helpful feature!

Comment: Thanks for the help bud! I was able to call the computed lifecycle inside the component and return a hook into the isAdded prop and then render the colors with v-bind:class - Works amazing :)

Comment: That sounds way more complex than necessary :)

Comment: Haha, would I be able to v-bind without a computed return? I tried, but my template wasn't showing up as it doesn't seem like it was recognizing the component.

Comment: I'd have to see what you tried to troubleshoot it. I recommend asking a new detailed question with reproduction steps (and ideally a codepen/codesandbox). Someone else will probably help you with it, as I'm not fully available at the moment.

Comment: It's no big deal at all tony, it's working which is great! Thanks for the help on the previous items, I learned so much!